# Map the exception of a failed future to Some, but isDefined does not work

Tags: scala, future

I just encountered a strange problem of scala. I mapped the exception of a failed future to Some type, but the isDefined function does not work for the Some variable. The code is just for testing:

```
val c =  Future.failed(Error("divide 0 !!!!!"))
val d = c.map(Some(_))
val e = d.map { v => if (v.isDefined) println("Got some!!!!")}
```

d is the type of `scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Nothing]]`, however, e cannot print "Got some!!!!", which means it believes d is not a Some type, but it is. Is there something I missed? Thank you for your help.

Comment: A failed Future will not perform any map, foreach, etc. because it's considered empty. In the end, e is just a Failure and nothing to print

Comment: Do you understand that at the moment you have a _failed_ future, everything gets shortcircuited.  You are also not mapping the error to Some. If you want to handle errors, use `transform` or `recover`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your explanation. I think the echo of the REPL misleads me. When I execute d, it echos "d: scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Nothing]] = Future(Failure(Error: divide 0 !!!!!)) ", which lets me think d has already been mapped with type of scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Nothing]], but it seems d was not mapped to Some because what you said it has a failed future.

Comment: @texasbruce, Thank you for your help, I understand now.

Comment: @xiaosu The output of the **REP** is correct, but you misread it _(not intentions to sound harsh)_ Lest start with `scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Nothing]]` the **REPL**, as any other compiler, only has information about the types in compile time, before the real execution of the code. Thus, since `c` is of _type_ `Future[Nothing]` and you call on it a `map(Some)` then, the type of the output has to be `Future[Some[Nothing]]` - Now this `= Future(Failure(Error: divide 0 !!!!!))`, is the runtime value of your code, it is a failed future, that will also be the value of `e`, since it is a failure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks a lot. Now I understand the whole thing. You save me twice:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map()` function is only applied if the execution of the `Future` was successful but not for the error cases. There are several options to solve your issue. The first but not so nice one is to make it explicit that the result of the `Future` contains an exception:

```
val c =  Future.failed(Error("divide 0 !!!!!"))
val d = c.failed.map(Some(_))
d.foreach { v => if (v.isDefined) println("Got some!!!!")}
```

But this solution only works if you know for sure that the `Future` contains an exception, which would ususally indicate some heavy design flaw in your code.

A different solution is to use `transform()` which allows you to also access the error case and turn it into a specific value you want to have:

```
val c =  Future.failed(Error("divide 0 !!!!!"))
val d = c.transform {
   case Success(value) => Success(Some(value))
   case Failure(error) => Success(Some(error))
}
d.foreach { v => if (v.isDefined) println("Got some!!!!")}
```

The most commonly used function to deal with those situations is the `recover()` function. Which is explicitly meant to be used to react on error cases and transform them into some form of result object:

```
val c =  Future.failed(Error("divide 0 !!!!!"))
val d = c.map(Some(_)).recover {
   case error:Error => Some(error)
}
d.foreach { v => if (v.isDefined) println("Got some!!!!")}
```

The `c.map(Some(_))` would only transform all successful cases. With `recover()` you would react on all `Throwable`s of type `Error` and transform them to `Some` as well. All other `Throwable`s would still be ignored for this specific case.

I hoped that helped you to move forward with your learnings ;-)

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. recover is the way I want. You indeed help me to move forward with my scala learning, Sincerely.

Comment: It seems the transform in this way does not compile, I tried it and the compiler complained " error: not enough arguments for method transform: (s: Nothing => S, f: Throwable => Throwable)(implicit executor: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[S].
Unspecified value parameter f.
       val d = c.transform { " , is it the scala version problem?  I used scala 2.11.11

Comment: [`transform[S](f: (Try[T]) ⇒ Try[S])`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/concurrent/Future.html#transform[S](s:T=%3ES,f:Throwable=%3EThrowable)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) is available only in Scala 2.12+.  The old `transform` has a different signature `transform[S](s: (T) ⇒ S, f: (Throwable) ⇒ Throwable)`.